# How to use routes defined in a parent module in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a module which has a controller and several templates. Now, I want to reference a controller which is located in the parent module. I tried it like this:

```
case Some(user) => Redirect(routes.Application.index)
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
[error]       case Some(user) => Redirect(routes.Application.index)
[error]                                   ^
```

I tried it also like this:

```
case Some(user) => Redirect(controllers.Application.index)
```

But I get still the same error. This error occurs also when I am trying to reference controllers which are part of the module.

I tried it like this: `controllers.module.Controller.action`.

In addition, I have the same problem when referencing views in a module which are actually located in a parent one.

For example, I want to reference the template `main` in a module:

```
@views.html.main
```

It throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into the "Aggregating reverse routers" - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AggregatingReverseRouters

For example, I have the sub-module "handlebars" and want to use routes from the main project in that sub-module. So I add the next string to the `build.sbt':

```
lazy val handlebars = (project in file("modules/handlebars"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
    .settings(
     aggregateReverseRoutes := Seq(root)
    )

lazy val root: Project = (project in file("."))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
    .aggregate(handlebars)
    .dependsOn(handlebars)
```

`aggregateReverseRoutes:= Seq(root)` says SBT first to compile routes from the `root` project and use them when compile `handlebars` project. You need also use implicit type for the `root` project like `root: Project` because of recursion in the dependencies.

The full story of the issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1390

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Could you please tell me how I can reference routes in my controller and templates?

Comment: I use Java, and my code in the sub-project looks `controllers.routes.Assets.versioned(new controllers.Assets.Asset(url)).toString()` where `url` is just a string. I think, you need to call `Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index)`.